# How can I suspend a whole command sequence in a shell?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

How can I suspend a whole command sequence in bash or zsh (or maybe some other shell)?

For example, if I run:

```
sleep 100; echo foo
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, `sleep` is suspended and put into background, but `echo` then runs immediately.

I would like the latter not to happen, i.e. `echo` should run after `sleep` was resumed and completed.

Answer (score 6):

Execute them from subshell:

```
( sleep 100 ; echo foo ; )
```

And ctrl+z will freeze whole subshell, not just one command:

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ( sleep 100; echo foo ; )
```